# How to time knockoutjs updates?

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs 2.2 with the deferred update plugin. I load a moderately large amount of data from the server via Ajax and use it to instantiate a bunch of objects (say about 5K objects, each with a half-a-dozen properties), some of which are then rendered in HTML. The entire process takes 10-20 seconds, but I am not sure where the time is going, and whether knockout is doing extra work that it shouldn't be doing.

The transfer and creation of the JSON structure is relatively quick; I've added timing calls to measure the creation of my data graph from the JSON data. What I would like to do now is measure the time it takes knockoutJS to compute the `ko.computed` values and to apply the bindings. How do I do that? What triggers the update (which has been deferred while the view model was being populated), and how do I bracket it to measure how long it took?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom binding that logs the time. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/WTYhs/

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
ko.bindingHandlers.logTime = {
  reset: function() {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
  },
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    console.log(value.msg + ' init: ' + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + ' ms');
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    if (typeof value.track == 'function')
      value.track();
    console.log(value.msg + ' update: ' + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) + ' ms');
  }
};
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work for multiple observables and computed values that are part of the the same view model.

Comment: Also, this seems to be measuring the difference in time from some starting time to when the init and update methods are evaluated, but that bundles in all sorts of other things rather than the time it takes to just update the view. It's also not clear to me when the observable gets evaluated in the fiddle example: does the `text: obs1` binding get evaluated first, and then the `logTime` binding? Or the other way around? In short, I don't quite see how to decorate a complex app with `logTime` bindings and how to restart the clock appropriately to separate different redraw events.

Comment: Binding are evaluated in left-to-right order (see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html#notes_for_multiple_bindings_on_a_single_element). You could add a function to reset `startTime`. I updated the example to show this.

Comment: That makes sense. But I still don't see how to apply this to a complex view model with dozens of `ko.observed` and `ko.computed` variables and arbitrary triggering actions

Comment: Try it in a few places and see what you get. You might be able to use a custom binding provider to automatically add it.